# Find the last digit of $(\sqrt{71}+1)^{71}+(\sqrt{71}-1)^{71}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

While teaching binomial expansion, one of my high school students asked me the following question:

What is the last digit of $(1+\sqrt{71})^{71}+(1-\sqrt{71})^{71}$?

I have absolutely no context on how he came up with it, but it seemed interesting enough.

Comment: that's not even an integer

Comment: what is the last digit of pi?  It doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, no, it's not.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas don't insult my intelligence. There is a plus sign in the question, and a minus sign in your question. The exact value is $178693478595018983488382230112063169948173084496504902915094015377408\sqrt{71}$. (Although as I write, the author has edited the question to make it correct.)

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Thanks. Let's say if it were edited as above, then the answer is 8?

Comment: Ah right! I missed that. I have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 6):

$(1+\sqrt{71})^{71} + (\sqrt{71}-1)^{71}$ is not an integer.

However, if you meant $(1+\sqrt{71})^{71} + (1-\sqrt{71})^{71}$, then it is indeed an integer.

If $x_n = (1+\sqrt{71})^n + (1-\sqrt{71})^n$, we then have $x_n$ to satisfy the recurrence
$$x_{n+1} = 2x_n + 70x_{n-1}$$
where $x_0 = 2$ and $x_1=2$. Hence, we see that
$$x_{n+1} = 2x_n \pmod{10}$$
Since $x_1 \equiv 2\pmod{10}$, we see that
$$x_n \equiv 2^n \pmod{10}$$ which implies
$$x_{4k} \equiv 6\pmod{10}$$
$$x_{4k+1} \equiv 2\pmod{10}$$
$$x_{4k+2} \equiv 4\pmod{10}$$
$$x_{4k+3} \equiv 8\pmod{10}$$
Since $71 \equiv3\pmod4$, we obtain that $x_{71} \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$, i.e., the last digit is $8$.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to get the same result is to note that $1$ is a square root of $71$ mod $10$. When the answer is an integer, replacing $71$ by $1$ (or the other root, $9$) will give the right answer. That yields $(1+1)^{71}+(1-1)^{71}=2^{71}$, as used here.

Comment: why does it satisfy the recurrence relation?

Comment: @Poseidonium I think that any sequence $x_n=c_1a^n+c_2b^n$ satisfies a linear two-term recurrence (that is, one of the form $x_{n+1}=Ax_n+Bx_{n-1}$ for some $A$ and $B$), but I'm not sure. EDIT: I think that $A=a+b$ and $B=-ab$, but I'd have to check. It certainly works in this case.

Comment: @Poseidonium Any expression of the form $c_1a^n + c_2 b^n$ satisfies the two term recurrence, $$x_{n+1} = (a+b)x_n - abx_{n-1}$$Look at [recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) in general.